# Access JS variables defined inside DIV

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access variables defined inside following div but unable to access them. I have tried something like this but getting undefined,

```
alert($('#docMode','#content_'+id).val() )

<div id="content_M-AMA-HID-1301-009R">
    <script>
        p.docs.loaded[p.docs.loaded.length]={
                            'isNewDoc' :  false,
                            'docMode' : 'edit',
                            'status' : 'Published',
                            'state' : 'active'
                           }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "variables defined inside a div". The JavaScript you have is completely separate from the HTML that surrounds it. All that code does is add an object to a `p.docs.loaded` array, with no connection to the id of the div which contains it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    p.docs.loaded[p.docs.loaded.length]={
                        'isNewDoc' :  false,
                        'docMode' : 'edit',
                        'status' : 'Published',
                        'state' : 'active'
                       }
</script>
```

Above script is added to the global space in JS.

You can't access it by the value of of the element it is in. Your `p.docs.loaded` array is accessible anywhere inside a script.

Comment: id which linked with "content_" is dynamic and in my architecture multiple forms can be opened in the "Tab" in same window. Such case id is dynamic and based on content_id I decide which form is opened in the tab.

Comment: However dynamic your id is, the JS variables inside the element doesn't care that. There is an issue in your architecture. You need to track the tab clicks and inform the JS variables about it. Putting script inside an element in your tab is not the way to go.